# Automate an interactive command which use /dev/tty

Tags: linux, shell, automation, ksh

well pretty much it's in the title.

I've a interactive command. This one ask for a password through `/dev/tty`. I use this command within a shell script. So the command should read the information through `stdin`. 
I've explored some ways to do this:

- Seek for an option to force stdin (*à la* `ssh` with the `-T` option)
- The easy ones, stream redirections
- The coprocesses (`|&`) to setup a communication between the current script and the coprocessed command
- I've tried named pipes

I'm running this script in a Korn shell (AIX). I can't use external tools such as expect or empty neither.

Do you have any clues ?

Comment: What is the command?  Why can't you use `expect` (which was written *explicitly* to solve this sort of problem)?

Comment: "can't use external tools such as expect" FRIED. Have fun.

Comment: FRIED? Now I'm hungry...

Comment: I can use expect because I can't install anything on the machines. The command is this one: [super](http://www.ucolick.org/~will/#super) version 3.6 _so I don't have -S option._